# Recursive function not working when using a for loop (Dijkstra's algorithm)

Tags: python, dijkstra

I have this function here:

```
    def shortestpath(graph,start,end,visited=[],distances={},predecessors={}):
        """Find the shortest path btw start & end nodes in a graph"""
        # detect if first time through, set current distance to zero
        if not visited: distances[start]=0
        # if we've found our end node, find the path to it, and return
        if start==end:
            path=[]
            while end != None:
                path.append(end)
                end=predecessors.get(end,None)
            return distances[start], path[::-1]
        # process neighbors as per algorithm, keep track of predecessors
        for neighbor in graph[start]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                neighbordist = distances.get(neighbor,float("inf"))
                tentativedist = distances[start] + graph[start][neighbor]
                if tentativedist < neighbordist:
                    distances[neighbor] = tentativedist
                    predecessors[neighbor]=start
        # neighbors processed, now mark the current node as visited 
        visited.append(start)
        # finds the closest unvisited node to the start 
        print(graph)
        unvisiteds = dict((k, distances.get(k,float("inf"))) for k in graph if k not in visited)
        
        closestnode = min(unvisiteds, key=unvisiteds.get)
        # now take the closest node and recurse, making it current 
        return shortestpath(graph,closestnode,end,visited,distances,predecessors)
```

And when running the function in just a single line, like the following:

```
shortestpath(graph, "A", "B")
```

it gives an expected output of: (4, ['A', 'B']) where the cost is 4 and the two nodes visited are A and B. However, when I try run it through a for loop I get errors.

This is my for loop:

```
    def djikstra(graph):

        keys = [i for i in graph.keys()]
        keys.pop(len(keys)-1)
        for i in keys:
            tmp=[]
            for j in keys:
                print(shortestpath(graph, i, j))
```

The error is the following:

```
File "weightedGraph.py", line 89, in shortestpath
        closestnode = min(unvisiteds, key=unvisiteds.get)
        ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

I am aware that the error is that unvisited is empty, but not sure why.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is not this complicated, it can be written very similarly to a bfs algorithm without recursion (see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: I understand that @Blackgaurd but, this works perfectly fine for my needs, and after many hours at this, it would be somewhat disheartening to simply rewrite it